# Display Sum for Multiple Columns

Tags: 2010, list-view, calculated-column-formula

I have a list with four columns to track different types of commissions (agent commissions and broker commissions):
**Agent**____**Amount**____**Broker**____**Amount**
John_____$50________Henry_____$50
Henry____$50________Henry_____$50

My current view will only give me a total of each agent and a total of each broker. So it has

- AGENT: John $50; Henry $50
- BROKER: Henry: $100

I need the totals for each person, but sometimes a person will receive Agent commissions **and** Broker commissions. I need the total of each person (combining the agent and the broker).

So I need it to show

- Henry = $150
- John = $50

How can I acheive this?

Answer (score 1):

Sums in Sharepoint is primiiitive and you can't do that OOTB.

The only way I could thing of is to use jquery to add the values. If they are many items, web part.

Answer (score 1):

You need a different data structure for that. Two lists with parent child relationship. Transaction list with Transaction ID and other transaction specific details that occur only once per transaction, e.g. Date. Fees list with Transaction ID, Name, Role (broker or agent), and fee amount.

Then you can sum fee amounts by Name.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of Agents + Brokers are static and limited, this can be achieved using having multiple calculated fields for each person. Other than that, there is no proper OOTB way.

However you can do this with some effort if you can use a Content Query Web Part by modifying the XSLT in it. There you can display it as much as you like.

If both of these are not possible, custom development is the way to go.